# Retrieving referenced documents with Morphia returns strange errors

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have been playing around with Morphia as I had issues with working with referenced documents using Spring Data for Mongodb. Below are snapshots of the data I have and the code...

Here are my User and Group classes (getters and setters omitted)

User Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Reference;



@Entity(value="users")
public class User {

@Id
    private String id;
private String username;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String email;
private long cellnumber;
private Date datejoined;
private boolean active;
private Account account;

@Reference(value="usergroups", lazy=true)
private List<Group> usergroups = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

The group class.

```
@Entity(value="groups")
public class Group {
@Id
private String id;
private String name;
private String description;
private long creationdate;

@Reference
private User user;

}
```

I am now running the following methods, named scenario1() and scenario2() in a main method.

```
    private void scenario1() {

    User newUser = setupUser(new User());
    datastore.save(newUser);
    Query<User> query = datastore.createQuery(User.class)
            .field("firstname").equal("Jome");
    User user = query.get();

    Account account = new Account();
    account.setBalance(0.0);
    account.setSmsvalue(0.18);

    UpdateOperations<User> update = datastore
            .createUpdateOperations(User.class);
    update.set("account", account);

    user.setAccount(account);
    datastore.save(user);
    List<Group> groups = query.get().getUsergroups();

    Group group1 = new Group();
    group1.setCreationdate(new Date().getTime());
    group1.setDescription("test group for first user");
    group1.setName("Group One");
    group1.setUser(query.get());
    datastore.save(group1);
    groups.add(group1);
    update.add("usergroups", group1);
    datastore.update(query, update);

    Group group2 = new Group();
    group2.setCreationdate(new Date().getTime());
    group2.setDescription("Another test group for first user");
    group2.setName("Group Two");
    group2.setUser(query.get());
    datastore.save(group2);
    groups.add(group2);

    update.add("usergroups", group2);

    datastore.update(query, update);

    System.out.println(user);
    List<Group> savedgroups = user.getUsergroups();
    System.out.println(savedgroups);
}
```

And this is the output

```
User [id=52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ac, username=jomski2013, firstname=Jome, lastname=Akpoduado, email=jomea@yookos.com, cellnumber=123456789]
[Group [id=52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ad, name=Group One, description=test group for first user, creationdate=1390971214880, owner=User [id=52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ac, username=jomski2013, firstname=Jome, lastname=Akpoduado, email=jomea@example.com, cellnumber=123456789]], Group [id=52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ae, name=Group Two, description=Another test group for first user, creationdate=1390971214884, owner=User [id=52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ac, username=jomski2013, firstname=Jome, lastname=Akpoduado, email=jomea@example.com, cellnumber=123456789]]]
```

and the view from the mongo console

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ac"),
"account" : {
    "balance" : 0,
    "smsvalue" : 0.18
},
"active" : true,
"cellnumber" : NumberLong("123456789"),
"className" : "org.imanmobile.sms.core.domain.User",
"datejoined" : ISODate("2014-01-29T04:53:34.746Z"),
"email" : "jomea@example.com",
"firstname" : "Jome",
"lastname" : "Akpoduado",
"password" : "$2a$10$c0SAy7eJZv06eqmAWQNUP.YrXtB7tDOdi11lkZqlAVgzVGU9RCbCS",
"usergroups" : [
    DBRef("groups", "52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ad"),
    DBRef("groups", "52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ae")
],
"username" : "jomski2013"
}

> db.groups.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ad"),
"className" : "org.imanmobile.sms.core.domain.Group",
"name" : "Group One",
"description" : "test group for first user",
"creationdate" : NumberLong("1390971214880"),
"user" : DBRef("users", "52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ac")
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ae"),
"className" : "org.imanmobile.sms.core.domain.Group",
"name" : "Group Two",
"description" : "Another test group for first user",
"creationdate" : NumberLong("1390971214884"),
"user" : DBRef("users", "52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ac")
}
```

However, when I subsequently run scenario2() below

```
    private void scenario2() {
    Query<User> query = datastore.createQuery(User.class);

    User user = query.field("username").equal("jomski2013").get();
    System.out.println("Number of groups: " + user.getUsergroups().size());
}
```

I get the error...

```
Caused by: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: The reference({ "$ref" : "groups", "$id" : "52e8894ef148a7f866b9f1ad" }) could not be fetched for org.imanmobile.sms.core.domain.User.usergroups
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.ReferenceMapper.resolveObject(ReferenceMapper.java:304)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.ReferenceMapper$1.eval(ReferenceMapper.java:243)
at org.mongodb.morphia.utils.IterHelper.loopOrSingle(IterHelper.java:89)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.ReferenceMapper.readCollection(ReferenceMapper.java:239)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.ReferenceMapper.fromDBObject(ReferenceMapper.java:163)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:602)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:584)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:294)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:71)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:58)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:53)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.get(QueryImpl.java:408)
at org.imanmobile.sms.PlayClass.scenario2(PlayClass.java:35)
at org.imanmobile.sms.PlayClass.run(PlayClass.java:29)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:644)
```

My question is why is Morphia able to fetch the groups that were saved the first time around but not subsequently? What's different or what should i really be looking out for or missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a type mismatch between the usergroups `DBRef` array and the documents these are referencing:

```
"usergroups" : [
    DBRef("groups", "52e82c05f148a7310a899a50"),
    DBRef("groups", "52e82c05f148a7310a899a4f")
]
```

The `$ref.id` are of type **String**

Whereas the `_id` in the groups collection are of type **ObjectId**:

`"_id" : ObjectId("52e82c05f148a7310a899a4f")`

and

`"_id" : ObjectId("52e82c05f148a7310a899a50")`

This is why the references could not be fetched.

You don't have to run a secondary query, this is done automatically by Morphia.

It's hard to determine the cause for this mismatch. Could it be that initially in your Java `Group` Class you had 
`private String ObjectId;` field, which had been used for insertion, and then later changed to `private String id;`?

In any case to fix this, you will have to wrap the `$ref.id` values inside `usergroups` array with an `ObjectId` to fix this:

```
"usergroups" : [
     DBRef("groups", ObjectId("52e82c05f148a7310a899a50")),
     DBRef("groups", ObjectId("52e82c05f148a7310a899a4f"))
]
```

You will also have to change your `Group` mapping accordingly (set the `id` property as `ObjectId`)

If you want to leave things as are (treat everything as Strings), just drop your database (I guess you are just experimenting), and start from fresh

Comment: I'm still getting the same issues. I edited the original question and added more code. The strange thing is when I run the method named scenario1() I get the result that follows the code. Running the method, scenario2() still gives the reference error I initially talked about.

Comment: Okay, what I eventually did was to set the ids for the User and Group class to ObjectId `private ObjectId id;` which seems to resolve the issue. However I have the impression that the ids can be String, int, Long etc? Does Morphia not recognize this? 
Voting this as the answer anyways... :)

Comment: Your finds show the _id properties as ObjectId but your code shows them as Strings.  Do you have a mix of data in your collections?  Strings as IDs are perfectly fine.